# two applications, how to test the communications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, integration-testing

I have two applications, say, A and B, talking to each other via API, now I am writing cucumber tests for A, I have two options:

1. Just test if the API is sent to B and stub the response from B
2. Setup test data on B from A (since i am testing A), and send real request to B, and record the request/response with VCR

I prefer option #1, but my coworker says it needs at least one real request to make sure the system (including A and B) is working.

My concern is:

1. How to prepare testing data for B from A's tests?
2. It's fragile to mix them together, anything changed on B may cause failure on A

Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

For the majority of your tests, stub the request/response, that way the test will pass when offline, or what not.

For one test, do a simple test that the external service is behaving as your stubs and mocks say it should.

E.G. Doing a get request still returns JSON with the attributes you expect to ensure your mocks are valid.

For the most part, "Up time" for an external service shouldn't be monitored by your test suite. Just that it behaves how you expect it to.

For the uptime concern you should look at the sysadmin side with Nagios, Pingdom, Pagerduty or what not.

Comment: the 2nd paragraph, i can see what you mean, you are trying to have a test to ensure the mock is not outdated, in my case, i think the tests should go to the B application (the external service), it should have a test to make sure it returns what it promises, thanks for the reply, but i can not agree with you on the 2nd paragraph, :D

Answer (score 0):

You are writing cucumber test, means it is an integration test.
For integration test, you'd better not mock anything, it's the last safety guard to keep your application save.

So you'd better send at last once real request to make sure your request is correct and what's more you can repeat this real request at any time.

the problem of solution 1:

1. You can not make sure B changing API implement
2. You can not make sure A send correct parameter to B
3. It's hard to mock complex request

So I sugguest create a sandbox app for B, make real request